# Did Obi-Wan ever take the trials to become a Jedi Knight?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, jedi-training

> **Qui-Gon:** Obi-Wan is ready
>   **Obi-Wan:** I am ready to face the trials.

So, Obi-Wan wanted to face the trials and change his rank from Padawan to Jedi Knight... Later, after the battle on Naboo we see Yoda granting Obi-Wan the rank of Knight after he killed Darth Maul...

[image]

*The image has been altered with a CGI Yoda, but it was the only pic I found from the scene :)*

> **Yoda:** Confer on you the level of Jedi Knight, the Council does...

Since, judging by the background they are still on Naboo, should we assume Obi-Wan never faced the trials to change rank? I can see how killing a Sith Lord is a huge trial, but isn't ther any protocol in this matter?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Obi-Wan didn't face the trials. As you've stated, there simply wasn't a gap between the Battle of Naboo and his meeting with Yoda when he could have traveled to Coruscant for testing.

This is confirmed in the [official novelisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_%28novel%29):

> They knew of what the young Padawan had done to save himself from the
>   Sith Lord in the melting pit after Qui-Gon had been struck down. It
>   took an act of extraordinary courage and strength of will. **Only a Jedi
>   Knight fully in tune with the Force could have saved himself against
>   such an adversary. Obi-Wan Kenobi had proved himself beyond everyone’s
>   expectations that day.**
>
> “Ready this time, he was,” Yoda acknowledged grudgingly. “Ready to
>   train the boy, he may not be.”
>
> “Defeating a Sith Lord in combat is a strong test of his readiness for
>   anything,” the Council leader pressed. His eyes stayed with Obi-Wan
>   and Anakin. “There is no doubt. The one who tested him was a Sith.”

---

This is further confirmed in the (until very recently) canon sourcebook; [The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force) where Anakin's own sidenotes state that Obi-Wan didn't have to take formal trials (and why);

[image]

[image]

There's also a section describing the circumstances under which a Jedi Padawan can bypass the trials, especially if the missions they've been on have resulted in their being tested beyond the limits of the formal trials anyway:

[image]

Comment: Well, this perfectly answer the *isn't ther any protocol in this matter* part of the question... There was a protocol even on bypassing the trials... Great answer!

Comment: So Obi-Wan passed the Trials of Skill & Courage by defeating Maul. I guess he passed the Trials of Spirit & Insight by telling Yoda where to stick it regarding Anakin afterwards, and the Trial of the Flesh by not attacking Padme in a dark room somewhere.

Comment: @Omegacron - Or y'know, not going to pieces after seeing his mentor eviscerated in front of him.

Comment: @Richard I feel like in the line of Jedis, lightsaber wounds are to be expected.

Comment: @TankorSmash - Except that for 1000+ years, the average Jedi hasn't even encountered a Sith, let alone fought one.

Comment: @Richard, oh, they did encounter them (Plagueis and Sidious were public political players, and I am pretty sure lots of Jedi encountered any one of those at least once), just weren't aware of that (the point about fighting one does stand, though; the ones who did didn't really come back to tell the tale).

Comment: In *The Clone Wars*, I think the Council suggested that Ahsoka Tano would also have been able to skip the trials as her dealing with the conspiracy, having being a fugitive then acquitted (in addition to everything else during the war), made for a complete test.

Comment: I don't like the idea of a Padawan advancing by killing someone. They're not warriors.  "War not make one great"  -- Master Yoda.  Now I understand it was all in tune with the force, etc, but it was still a combat trial.

Comment: @JoeC - *Defeating* them is sufficient. Killing them isn't necessary to pass the trial, but obviously sometimes when you're defeating someone, you kill them in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading somewhere that seeing the death of Qui-Gon Jinn and subsequently confronting Darth Maul *was* Obi-Wan's trial. There may have existed a *formal* set of trials for Jedi who's circumstances never lent to them receiving the Trials in a *real-live* situation - but (as rigid as they got in the waning days of the Republic) the Jedi Order did *not* get to the point of insisting on the *formaized* trials in situations where circumstances gave the necessary trials in real-life.